# How to connect MacBook Pro (2020) to ultra widescreen monitor?

Tags: macos, display, hdmi

I have an ultrawide monitor that's 3840 X 1200. It works perfectly fine with my windows laptop.

I now need to connect my work MacBook Pro provided to me, but under the list of resolutions (and extended hidden resolutions) none of them come close.

Is it a matter of the cable I'm using? I'm using a HDMI cable with a usb-c adaptor on the end to connect it to the MacBook.

Comment: How do you connect it to the windows laptop?

Comment: Cheap cables and adapters can ruin an otherwise compatible monitor in my experience. I’ve listed one vendor if you don’t want to buy adapters from Apple in my answer.

Answer (score 4):

Besides the other answer, you might have better results with a **DisplayPort** cable if your monitor supports it. My 3440x1440 monitor for instance works at 100hz with DisplayPort and only 60hz with HDMI.

Comment: I pretty much guarantee that you'll get better results with a DisplayPort cable as you don't have to convert from the native DisplayPort signal from the Mac.  No conversion = better reliability!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the cable is very important. Some HDMI cables do not support a 4k display signal at all, and some only at a lower refresh rate of 30 Hz. You definitely want a version 2.0 or higher HDMI cable capable of support 4k at 60 Hz.

Answer (score 0):

I usually follow along this closely and have excellent success.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202351

Once you confirm how the display works and how you want to convert it to Thunderbolt 3 you can shop for adapters / cables and get rolling. The current (2019/2020) hardware can run one 6K, one 5K, or up to two 4K displays (or better).

As for specifics I tend to choose high quality adapters and cables. Monoprice is excellent value if you want to save on what Apple sells online for HDMI or choose a display port cable for your specific display.